# Clone GCE instance and fix mounting previous disks

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a new instance (`instance-2`) by clicking "create similar" in an existing instance (`instance-1`).

I have then created the boot disk (`instance-2-disk`) from existing snapshot
(`instance-1-disk-snapshot`) on the previous instance and a data ssd secondary disk (`instance-2-disk-data`) also from a snapshot of (`instance-1-disk-data-snapshot`).

However the machine doesn't want to bootup, because it is still trying to attache the `instance-1-disk-data`. This is an output of the machine's serial console:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device instance-1-disk-data.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File…ogle-instance-1-disk-data.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /data.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

How can I tell the system to expect the instance-2-disk-data even though the instance has correctly set the instance-2-disk-data?

Comment: Create another instance. Attach **instance-2-disk** as a secondary disk. Figure out what is attaching **instance-1-disk-data** and modify (remove that dependency). You should then be able to create a new instance that boots so that you can attach **instance-2-disk-data**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Addition to John Hanley. Here are the detailed steps

1. Go to your instance-2 VM
2. Shut Down
3. Edit
4. Detached Boot disk
5. Custom Image
6. Select Project > Select Image
7. Save and Start Server

In case you want to do it again by scratch

1. Go to you instance-1 VM
2. Select Disk > Create Snapshot
3. Go to Compute Engine > Snapshot
4. Select Snapshot
5. Create Instance
6. Configure VM then Create